# Django rest: accessing all related objects using ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I'm stuck and I don't know what's wrong... to me it's identical to the "Nested relationships" example in the DRF API guide but something is not right...

**MODEL**

```
class PlayerSquadra(models.Model):
    
    player = models.ForeignKey(
       'app_player.Player',
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
       verbose_name=_('giocatore'),
       related_name='player_squadraplayer',
    )

    squadra = models.ForeignKey(
        'app_stagione.Squadra',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_('squadra'),
        related_name='squadra_squadraplayer'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.player)
```

**URL**

```
router.register(r'squadraJSON/(?P<squadra>.*)', views.SquadraViewSet)
```

**VIEW**

```
class SquadraViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Squadra.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SquadraSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        laSquadra = self.kwargs['squadra']
        queryset = Squadra.objects.filter(id=int(laSquadra))
        return queryset
```

**SERIALIZER**

```
class PlayerSquadraSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerSquadra
        fields = '__all__'

class SquadraSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    playersquadra = PlayerSquadraSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Squadra
        fields = ['nomeSquadra','id','playersquadra']
```

What I get when I call http://192.168.0.102:8000/squadraJSON/26/ is:

```
GET /squadraJSON/26/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "nomeSquadra": "prova2",
        "id": 26
    }
]
```

And no errors... While I expect something like this:

```
GET /squadraJSON/26/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "nomeSquadra": "prova2",
        "id": 26
        "playersquadra": [
            {'id': 1, 'firstName': 'Michael', 'lastName': 'Jordan',...},
            {'id': 2, 'firstName': 'Larry', 'lastName': 'Bird',...},
            ...
        ],
    }
]
```

Could you give me some hint why I'm not getting all the players belonging to Squadra with id=26? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `related_name` to access all the related `PlayerSquadra`, which is `squadra_squadraplayer`, so:

```
class SquadraSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    playersquadra = PlayerSquadraSerializer(
        many=True, read_only=True, source='squadra_squadraplayer',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Squadra
        fields = ['nomeSquadra','id','playersquadra']
```

or:

```
class SquadraSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # This will change the name of the key to squadra_squadraplayer
    squadra_squadraplayer = PlayerSquadraSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Squadra
        fields = ['nomeSquadra','id','squadra_squadraplayer']
```

or even:

```
class SquadraSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    playersquadra = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Squadra
        fields = ['nomeSquadra','id','playersquadra']
    
    def get_playersquadra(self, obj):
        return PlayerSquadraSerializer(
            obj.squadra_squadraplayer, many=True, read_only=True,
        ).data
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer... just a comment: I tried the first proposed solution and works but what about the [example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#:~:text=the%20serializer%20field.-,Example,-For%20example%2C%20the) in DRF documentation? Is it just missing the source argument (so it could be useful to correct it) and it doesn't work as it is or am I missing something? Thanks again for helping!

Comment: It didn't need the source argument because the field name (`tracks`) matches the `related_name` of `track` from `albums`: `album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: This is also shown on my 2nd example. `squadra_squadraplayer` matches the related name so no need to define `source`. Let me know if it's not clear

Comment: Another example is if you want to use `playersquadra` in the serializer without specifying source, change the related name of squadra foreign key from `squadra_squadraplayer` to `playersquadra` in the `PlayerSquadra` model